# OpenLayers 4 Displaying GeoJSON Point Data

Tags: openlayers, geojson, geodjango

I'm struggling to properly display my GeoJSON data which is being serialized from a GeoDjango model, though hopefully that isn't relevant to the issue at hand.

I copy and pasted a GeoJSON example from the OL4 docs and then tried to add in my own GeoJSON just to try to get it displaying properly but I have so far been unsuccessful.

Here's the [broken jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TechnoConserve/g3a2ywdj/2/) to show my problem. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. The GeoJSON has an incorrect crs section. Just remove that.
2. When reading the features, you have to configure `{featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}` for the readFeatures call, to make sure that features are transformed to the view projection.

Note that (2) only applies when you configure the source with `features`. When you configure it with a `url` and a `format`, the features will automatically be transformed to the view projection.

I have updated your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oq911uoe/.

Comment: Ah thank you! That's interesting though, since the crs section is auto-generated by a Django core method.